# multiprocessing.Pool.map stuck at last Process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am running a program in pycharm on a linux server which uses `multiprocessing.Pool().map` for increased performance.

The code looks something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

for episode in episodes:
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as mpool:
        func_part = partial(worker_function)
        mpool.map(func_part, range(step))
```

The weird thing is that it runs perfectly fine on my Windows 10 Laptop but as soon as I try to run it on a linux server the program gets stuck at the exact last Process `measurement count 241/242`, so right before proceeding to the next iteration of the loop e.g. the next episode.

[image]

No error message given. I am running pycharm on both machines. The `Step` layer is where I placed the `multiprocessing.Pool().map` function.

**Edit:**

I've added `mpool.close()` and `mpool.join()` but it does seem to have no effect:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

for episode in episodes:
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as mpool:
        func_part = partial(worker_function)
        mpool.map(func_part, range(step))
        mpool.close()
        mpool.join()
```

It still gets stuck at the last process.

**Edit2:**

This is the worker function:

```
def worker_func(steplength, episode, episodes, env, agent, state, log_data_qvalues, log_data, steps):
    env.time_ = step
    action = agent.act(state, env)                                                                               # given the state, the agent acts (eps-greedy) either by choosing randomly or relying on its own prediction (weights are considered here to sum up the q-values of all objectives)
    next_state, reward = env.steplength(action, state)                                                                # given the action, the environment gives back the next_state and the reward for the transaction for all objectives seperately
    agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, env.future_reward)                                        # agent puts the experience in his memory
    q_values = agent.model.predict(np.reshape(state, [1, env.state_size]))                                      # This part is not necessary for the framework, but lets the agent predict every time_ to
    start = 0                                                                                                   # to store the development of the prediction and to investigate the development of the Q-values
    machine_start = 0
    for counter, machine in enumerate(env.list_of_machines):
        liste = [episode, steplength, state[counter]]
        q_values_objectives = []
        for objective in range(1, env.number_of_objectives + 1):
            liste.append(objective)
            liste.append(q_values[0][start:machine.actions + start])
            start = int(agent.action_size / env.number_of_objectives) + start
        log_data_qvalues.append(liste)
        machine_start += machine.actions
        start = machine_start
    state = next_state
    steps.append(state)
    env.current_step += 1
    if len(agent.memory) > agent.batch_size:                                                                    # If the agent has collected more than batch_size-experience, the networks of the agents are starting
        agent.replay(env)                                                                                       # to be trained, with the replay function, batch-size- samples from the memory of the agents are selected
    agent.update_target_model()                                                                                 # the Q-target is updated after one batch-training
    if steplength == env.steplength-2:                                                                                # for plotting the process during training
        #agent.update_target_model()
        print(f'Episode: {episode + 1}/{episodes}    Score: {steplength}    e: {agent.epsilon:.5}')
        log_data.append([episode, agent.epsilon])
```

As you can see it uses several classes to pass attributes. I don't know how I would reproduce it. I am still experimenting on where the process gets stuck exactly. The worker function communicates with the `env` and the `agent` class and passes information that is required to train a neural network. The `agent` class controls the learning process while the `env` class simulates the environment the network has control over.

**step** is an integer variable:

```
step = 12
```

Comment: With just that few lines code your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, sorry

Comment: Well we're gonna need the to see the `worker_function` and `step`, otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Using `with multiprocessing.Pool()`, inside a `for ...` loop is a antipattern. The difference between *Windows* and *Linux* results in the implementation of how processes are spawned. Try to add a `time.sleep(...` after `.join()`. **No**, I can't explain why.

Comment: @jzzfs I added the `worker_function`. @stovfl thanks for this insight. I have been working on windows with `Pool()` inside of `for loops` without any problem, though I am not experienced with the `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: One step towards a minimal reproducible example would be to remove pycharm from the picture. You are not running your code with pycharm, you are running your code in an interpreter (that may read some environment variables configured by pycharm). Try to run your code in a standard terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling

```
mpool.close()
mpool.join()
```

at the end?

---

EDIT

The problem is not w/ `multiprocessing` but with the `measurement count` part. According to the screenshot, the pool map successfully ends w/ step 11 (`range(12)` starts at 0). `measurement count` is nowhere to be seen in the provided snippets to try debugging that part.

Comment: I did but it does not change anything. (See edit section)